# Chrome Device Preview Broken?

Tags: responsive-design, google-chrome-devtools

I'm extremely confused by the behavior that I'm getting trying to do responsive design. I can't really put it into words, but [this](https://gfycat.com/ZealousIllustriousFritillarybutterfly) should show the problem.

The code I'm using for this test is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9yw7ps7g/). Of note is the media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

Why does this query not trigger when the Device Preview viewport has a width less than 425px?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when you are using device mode(not exactly sure why). but most of the times it works well in incognito mode. Alternatively you clear site data and navigate to your site in device mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem just now, it was because I'd forgot to set the viewport up in my html file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```